# Get foldername from url with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get folder name from a URL. For example:

```
http://example.com/foldername/test.html
```

I can get the pathname like `/foldername/test.html` with `window.location.pathname` and then I just need get `"foldername"`.

How can I get `"foldername"` form current URL with JavaScript? Please let me know. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Just split and get the third result

```js
var string = "http://example.com/foldername/test.html"
console.log(string.split("/")[3])
```

Or using the pathname :

```js
var string = "/foldername/test.html"
console.log(string.split("/")[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the URL to the `URL()` constructor to create a new instance. After that, you can access the `pathname`, split by the path separator, filter out empty and file names tokens, and recombine.

```js
const pathJoin = (parts, sep) => {
   const separator = sep || '/', replace = new RegExp(`${separator}{1,}`, 'g');
   return parts.join(separator).replace(replace, separator);
}

const fullUrlPath = (url) => {
  if (typeof url === 'string') url = new URL(url);
  return pathJoin(url.pathname.split('/')
    .filter(path => path.trim() !== '' && !/^[\S]+\.[\S]+$/.test(path)));
};
  
console.log(fullUrlPath('http://example.com/foldername/test.html'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy and simple see

```js
//check for folder
var foldername = (location.href).split("/")[3];

console.log(foldername);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]`

Answer (score -2):

You already have the answer.
You just need to work your pathname with something like:

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").map((folder)=>console.log(folder))
```

Comment: This is not a proper use of `map()`

Comment: I think you mean `forEach` instead?